# DialogInterface.dismiss() not working when followed by startActivity(Intent)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

My Andorid app is checking for Location service settings every time when resumed and then showing a pop up to user to enable it if disabled. This is the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setTitle("Location Services Disabled");
dialog.setMessage("This app needs location services to be enabled. We recommend to keep it on");
dialog.setPositiveButton("Enable", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
        //paramDialogInterface.cancel();
        paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
        finish();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

**Problem:**

- Observation 1 : When user clicks on Enable button, Location Settings is launched. After turning on the Location and pressing back button my app is resumed but it doesn't hide the dialog.
- Observation 2 : I tried commenting the startActivity line and then dilog is getting dismissed with the same code.

Comment: Have you tried making the dialog a dialog activity then when you return to the dialog activity you can call finish().

Comment: Any chance to remember if and how you solved this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full source code. What is happening dialog getting dismissed but after returning to the activity you're showing the dialog again! Check you condition!

Answer (score 0):

instead of `'startActivity'` you should be constructing an `Intent` and use `**startActivityForResult()**` along with 'A request code'

Something like this.

```
 startActivityForResult(myIntent , YOUR_ENABLE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

then on your

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == YOUR_ENABLE_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user came back from the Enable Location Activity
            // Dismiss the Dialog
        } 
    }
}
```

Remember that if you only want to dismiss the Dialog even if user did not enable it you can always call `dialog.Dismiss();` on  `onActivityResult();`

if you need more information on how to work with this you can always refer to the Android Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to dismiss the dialog programmatically as this is the default behavior after processing click of a button in Dialog.

In all probability you are showing the dialog in your **onResume** or **onStart** method. Therefore whenever one of those lifecycle methods are called (when returning back from Settings), your dialog is shown. If that is the case, then easiest solution is to move that code out of those lifecycle methods and restructure your logic to show dialog.